# C# getter setter spilt string in List

Tags: c#

How can I use C# get set properties to split string property ,EndorseImageLink, with comma into LIST EndorseImage**s**Link
 BUT my code seem to recursive call

```
public string EndorseImageLink { get; set; }
    public List<string> EndorseImagesLink
            {
                get { return this.EndorseImagesLink; }
                set
                {

                    foreach (var endorseImageUrl in this.EndorseImageLink.Split(','))
                    {
                        if (endorseImageUrl.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
                        {
                            this.EndorseImagesLink.Add(endorseImageUrl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hint: use underlying variable _endorseImagesLink.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Surely this would be in the setter for the `string` property, not the list?  Most would expect that if you set the `List` with a value then that's what will be set - you're entirely ignoring the `value`.

Comment: @CharlesMager thanks, I ignored the 'value' ,so I made myself muddled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood , but do you want something like that ?

```
    public string EndorseImageLink
    {
        set
        {
            EndorseImagesLink.Clear();
            foreach (var endorseImageUrl in value.Split(',').Where(endorseImageUrl => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(endorseImageUrl)))
            {
                EndorseImagesLink.Add(endorseImageUrl);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<string> EndorseImagesLink
    {
        get { return _endorseImagesLink ?? (_endorseImagesLink = new List<string>()); }
        private set { _endorseImagesLink = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot some basics,to assign value to the property ,thanks your snippet code

Answer (score 1):

It causes recursive calls, because in the getter of EndorseImagesLink you return the same EndorseImagesLink property, wich will call the same getter again and again.
Something like this would be correct:

```
private List<string> endorseImagesLink;
public List<sting> EndorseImagesLink
{
    get { return this.endorseImagesLink; }
    set { this.endorseImagesLink = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.I must be noted

Answer (score 0):

You need a private variable that the property accesses

```
private List<string> _endorseImagesLink = new List<string> ();
public List<string> EndorseImagesLink
        {
            get { return _endorseImagesLink ; }
            set
            {
                _endorseImagesLink.Clear();
                foreach (var endorseImageUrl in this.EndorseImageLink.Split(','))
                {
                    if (endorseImageUrl.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
                    {
                        _endorseImagesLink .Add(endorseImageUrl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What happens is that you try to set the property in its own `setter`. This then starts the recursive loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're in a bit of a muddle.  I don't think you want to use the setter for `EndorseImagesLink` at all - this is effectively a computed property that depends on the `string`.

There are two approaches.  You could set this each time that the `string` is set:

```
private string _linksDelimited;

public string LinksDelimited
{
    get { return _linksDelimited; }
    set
    {
        _linksDelimited = value;
        Links = value.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> Links { get; private set; } = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

Or you could just compute the result on demand:

```
public string LinksDelimited { get; set; } = string.Empty;

public IEnumerable<string> Links
    => LinksDelimited.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Note in both cases I've used the `string.Split` overload that will remove empty entries - you don't need to do this manually.